# Flex - Access ViewNavigators inside TabbedViewNavigatorApplication from View?

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air

I have a `TabbedViewNavigatorApplication` android application on Flex. I have various Spark `View`s that contain the contents of my app. I also have `ViewNavigator`s inside `TabbedViewNavigatorApplication`. I want to disable some of the `ViewNavigator`s if a certain process is going on in one of my `View`s. So my question is, how do I reference to ViewNavigators from within Spark `View`?

I already tried `this.parent.idOfOneOfMyVieNavigator.enabled = false;` but Flash Builder isn't recognizing `idOfOneOfMyVieNavigator` so I figured it's not gonna work. Plus, it gives me the error: *Access of undefined property idOfOneOfMyVieNavigator*

Answer (score 0):

Try [`View.navigator`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html#navigator) to get the containing navigator:

```
myView.navigator.enabled = false;
```

(Also, with skins in play, `owner` may have been a better first guess than `parent`.)

Since you have multiple `ViewNavigator`s, you may be better off going directly to the application:

```
var myApp:MyApplication = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as MyApplication;
myApp.firstNavigator.enabled = true;
myApp.secondNavigator.enabled = false;
```

Obviously if this code is in the `View`, you'll be limited in how you can reuse the code, but that may not be an issue for you.

Comment: I didn't quite get how I'd use this, I tried to reference `View.navigator.idOfMyViewNavigator.enabled = false;` but it didn't work.

Comment: My first example would just get you the navigator--it looks like you may want the application (which contains multiple navigators).  I updated my answer.